# Set ethers provider to use any injected web3 providers

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

Using MetaMask provider to detect MetaMask as provider and Etherprojects provider to set provider.

`import { ExternalProvider, Web3Provider } from '@ethersproject/providers'; import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';`

Checking for MetaMask provider only and setting metamask as provider.

```
export default class Dapp extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  
provider!: Web3Provider;
 

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const browserProvider = await detectEthereumProvider() as ExternalProvider;

    if (browserProvider?.isMetaMask !== true) {
      this.setError( 
      );
    }

    this.provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(browserProvider);

    this.registerWalletEvents(browserProvider);

    await this.initWallet();
  }
```

I had resolved this issue to detect any injected web3 provider last week accidentally I couldn't save the code now I cannot figure how I got it to work with any web3 provider wallets like Trust Wallet or Brave Wallet.